# Unable to get selected file from file chooser and show in list view

Tags: android

I have a file chooser in android and I want to get the path of the selected file and to show it in a listview.

Here is my code:

```
switch(requestCode){
case 1:
if(resultCode=Activity.RESULT_OK){
Uri contactData=data.getData();
Cursor c =managedQuery(contactData, null,null,null,null);
c.moveToFirst();
String filename;
filename=c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_display_name");
filenames.add(filename);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,filenames);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But it gives me NullPointerException when I am adding the filename to the ArrayList
Please help.

Comment: If filename==null then do not add. Update your code please.

Comment: And a file name is no file path. Obtaining a file name is ok. But trying to get a path is bad if you have a nice uri.

Comment: `managedQuery()` has been deprecated for nearly a decade. There is no requirement for any `Uri` to have some column named `_display_name`. A display name is largely unrelated to a path. And, most likely, there is no path relevant for your `Uri`. If you would update your [mcve] to show where your `Uri` is coming from, we might be able to make some recommendations on what you should be showing the user.